# how to draw wpf ui with many many controls?

Tags: wpf, user-interface

My application UI use Tab control.
One of the tab has 20 groupboxes (in scrollviwer), and each groupbox contents 300 textbox with a name (label) above the textbox (not one on one match). 
When the app running (not yet), each textbox will display a byte value from the buffer.
I am manually drawing this groupbox, it is too much work.  I am trying use itemcontrol to draw the textboxes, but don't know how to make a new line since there are name-value pair.

Any solution will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use an ItemControl with a DataTemplate, where the DataTemplate represents one key-value pair.

```
              <ItemsControl>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                           <TextBlock Text="Hi I am a label" />
                           <TextBox />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Thank you Julien for your quick answer.  I just updated my question, say "name-textboxes" pair is not real dictionary pair.  Some case, one textbox with one name, other cases 4 or 10 boxes with one name.  Can I still use this itemscontrol pattern?  I am new to wpf.

Comment: Well it sounds like you need an ItemsControl in the DataTemplate of your ItemsControl. So you'd have the template like above but inside the DataTemplate you would have another ItemsControl to draw all your textboxes

Comment: Finally I decided drawing those titles manually and using <ItemsControl> for data only.  It was still a lots work, but it's done :)